# What happened to Black Clover? Was the anime canceled?

Tags: black-clover

A few days ago (March 30, 2021), what seems to be the "last" episode of Black Clover aired. [MyAnimeList now shows it as Finished Airing](https://myanimelist.net/anime/34572/Black_Clover). However, it is clear the story is not over. Black Clover has been airing every week for over three years. Why did it stop now? Was the anime canceled? Is it changing into the standard "release by season" with gaps of several months (like Boku no Hero Academia for example)? Is there any official declaration about it?

*(please don't give spoilers from the manga)*

Answer (score 3):

Black Clover is trying to avoid having a lot of fillers by giving the anime a break. During the past few months, the anime sped up the storyline which led to it coming close to the manga's ongoing story. Once an anime finishes its manga's ongoing story, it most of the times runs out of source material for newer content. So them deciding to stop the anime was a good choice. All of this is in the black clovers comic book. They are making a currently a black clover movie that continues the series, so that the author of black clover can have some time to write the manga.